# Can I enable both Client Side and SSR in JHipster?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have existing `jhipster` application with `React` front end. I am having issue with the `React-Helmet` where I am unable to show preview page on WhatsApp and Facebook.

Is it possible to have SSR for a single JSP file without losing the existing React Front End ? If it is could anyone give pointers which part needs adjustment ?

Comment: First in JHipster you would use provided Thymeleaf rather than JSP but I'm not sure to understand your point. Do you want to have 2 pages: index.html for React and another one for preview page with different URL? Or do you want to render React app on server like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53652083/server-side-rendering-react-in-java-springboot which is quite hard and ready for prime time

Comment: I would like to keep `index.html` for `React` and another one for preview page with different url. I was thinking something like `mydomain/article/1234`. Is it doable ?

Comment: Sure just follow the doc https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/ it works in JHipster